# Solving $Ax=b$ when no exact solution exists

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

When $b$ does not lie in column space of $A$, $Ax=b$ does not have a solution.Hence we project $b$ onto the subspace spanned by $A$ and solve the equation.

My question is: does multiplying the equation $Ax=b$ by $A'$ on both sides yield the same solution?

I.e $A'Ax=A'b$  , this yeilds $x=(A'A)^{-1}  A'b$ which is the approximate solution
Does any matrix equality hold when we multiply both sides by a matrix(making sure dimensions are consistent)

Comment: I don't think I really get the first two lines. $x$ is the unknown, what does it belong to? The first sentence would work if like: "when $b$ does not lie,...". Moreover, there are many way to project $b$ onto a subspace, and is of no use to project a vector to obtain another equation which is poorly related to your one. Maybe I misunderstood your explanation..

Comment: X belongs to Rn, A belongs to R m*n, does the equation Ax=b and A'*A*x=A'b have same solution

Comment: Look at the answer then.. It explains you that you should choose a proper projection and corrects the same things I do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: yes, more or less. You meant "when $b$ does not lie in the column space" rather than "when $x$ does not lie in the column space." Once you fix that, the "multiply by the transpose" thing does indeed work in general.

And when you do that, the thing you get $(A'A)^{-1}A'$ is called the "Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse", which should let you read up on explanations on why it gives the result you ask about. (A similar thing works for underdetermined systems, and is worth reading about.)

(This whole technique works only when the projection from $b$ to the range of $A$ is the orthogonal projection in euclidean space.)

Suggestion: For future questions, go ahead and write a few more words to set context, so that others **know**, rather than having to guess, what you're talking about.  In this case, you might have said "Suppose $A$ is an $n \times k$ matrix representing a linear transformation from $R^k$ to $R^n$, with $k < n$. ..."